# calling a button through javascript ASP.NET MVC dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a HTML button through a JavaScript function that responds on a drop down list change. But for some reason it's not finding the correct id.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetReport", "Choices",
  new AjaxOptions() {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "reportResults",
  }
)) {
  @Html.DropDownList("q",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["YearTermList"], htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
  <br />
  @Html.DropDownList("ChartList", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
  <br />
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="ShowList" value="Search"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#YearTermList").change(function () {
      $("#ShowList").click();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The JavaScript function doesn't submit the button on the drop down list change.

Comment: You don't have any elements with `id="YearTermList"` (just `id="q"` and `id="ChartList"`).

Answer (score 0):

Selector `$("#YearTermList")` finds nothing, because the is no id `YearTermList` in markup.

You should either add `id="YearTermList"` where you want to add listener or change the selector of listener from `#YearTermList` to `#q`, `#ChartList` or other.